# How to track number of spam clicks on a button in WPF

Tags: wpf, button

I have a button that skips a video on by x seconds. if a user spam clicks that button my video updates over and over again which is an expensive operation. What is the best way to stop a user spamming the button? I am using a routed ui command and want to add up the seconds and do 1 operation. Is a delay timer best practice here? delay the operation for 10ms and reset the delay on every click? or is there something built into wpf that can help?

UPDATE: 
I would like to track the number of clicks a user is making during the spam click of the button

Comment: When user hits 5 times per second - do you want update one time per this second or 5 times per next 5 seconds?

Comment: I'd just like the update to happen once and the time to be worked out by the number of times the button was hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone one step further with this and created my own command.

This command works like a relay command but will delay if you set a delay time span in initialisation. you can retrieve the number of times it was clicked in your execute method.

Initialise the command:

```
ICommand DelayedClickCommand = new DelayedCommand(ExecuteDelayedClickCommand, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
```

Create an execute method and retrive the amount of times clicked:

```
    private void ExecuteClickCommand()
    {
        TimesClicked = ((DelayedCommand)ClickCommand).TimesClicked;
    }
```

and here is the command class:

```
public class DelayedCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _methodToExecute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecuteEvaluator;
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;

    public int TimesClicked;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// A command to stop the spamming of the <see cref="Execute"/> method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodToExecute">Method to run when command executes</param>
    /// <param name="canExecuteEvaluator">Method used to determine if the command can execute</param>
    /// <param name="delayTime">The cool down period required between click execution</param>
    public DelayedCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator, TimeSpan delayTime)
    {
        _methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
        _canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;

        _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(delayTime, DispatcherPriority.Normal, Callback, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A command to stop the spamming of the <see cref="Execute"/> method
    /// when no <see cref="CanExecute"/> method is required
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodToExecute">Method to run when command executes</param>
    /// <param name="delayTime">The cool down period required between click execution</param>
    public DelayedCommand(Action methodToExecute, TimeSpan delayTime)
        : this(methodToExecute, null, delayTime)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A command when only a <see cref="Execute"/> method is needed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodToExecute">Method to run when command executes</param>
    public DelayedCommand(Action methodToExecute)
        : this(methodToExecute, null, TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A command taking a <see cref="Execute"/> Method and a <see cref="CanExecute"/> method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodToExecute">Method to run when command executes</param>
    /// <param name="canExecuteEvaluator">Method used to determine if the command can execute</param>
    public DelayedCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
        : this(methodToExecute, canExecuteEvaluator, TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecuteEvaluator == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (!_dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled)
            TimesClicked = 0;

        TimesClicked++;

        _dispatcherTimer?.Stop();
        _dispatcherTimer?.Start();
    }

    private void Callback(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        _methodToExecute.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Note: that when you spam click this command execute will not run untill 200ms after the last click was performed, giving a lagging effect. I have added a sample project to git hub and will add better commands for this question on there

https://github.com/sgreaves1/DelayedCommands

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about build-in *Command* ability to do this, but you can do it with delay (updated based on comments):

```
private int spamCount = 0;

private int delayValue = 0;

private object isHoldedLock = new object(); 

private bool isHolded = false;

public bool CanProceed(int delay, Action updateVideo)
{
    lock (this.isHoldedLock)
    {
        if (this.isHolded)
        {
            this.spamCount++;

            this.delayValue = delay;

            return false;
        }

        this.isHolded = true;
        this.delayValue = delay;

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (this.delayValue > 0)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100);

                this.delayValue -= 100;
            }

            updateVideo();

            lock (this.isHoldedLock)
            {
                this.isHolded = false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

Process/reset `spamCount` value inside `SkipVideo` any way you need.

And using in your command handler:

```
private void InvokedFromCommand()
{
    if (CanProceed(1000, SkipVideo()))
    {
        // SkipVideo();
    }
}
```

Comment: with this code can i reset the delay every time the command is Invoked?

Comment: In that case delay will expire after _latest_ time user clicked button - if user will clicking 10 seconds without stopping, he will only able to do skip if he then click after eleventh second. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No sorry, what i mean is if he clicks once, the timer starts, if he clicks again within 10 seconds the timer restarts, if he then doesnt click after that 10 seconds i will update the video.

Comment: I updated the answer. Add locks for `delayValue` if need.

Comment: Forgot to trigger video update after delay expired, answer updated again.

Comment: 2 issues with the update, isHolded is not a reference type as required by the lock statement

and task.run is ambiguous invocation

Comment: `Nullable` is struct, my bad. Ambiguous invocation is result of previous error, should be gone.

Comment: this will work, but doesnt keep track of the number of times the user spam clicked the button

Comment: Now you have spam count

Answer (score 0):

I really hope the async way works, while we were trying that out i created a solution, feel free to tell me all i did wrong and any bad practices.

I decided to use dispatcher timer for this even though i didn't really want to. couldn't find any better practices online.

```
private TimeSpan overallSkipSpeed = TimeSpan.Zero;
private readonly TimeSpan Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400);
private DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;
private TimeSpan _time;

// Execute command function
public void ExecuteClickCommand()
{
    // If the timer isn't going create and start it
    if (_dispatcherTimer == null)
    {
        overallSkipSpeed = TimeSpanToModifyBy(skipSpeed, skipForward);
        _time = Interval;

        _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer(Interval, DispatcherPriority.Normal, Tick, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
        _dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
    else // If the timer is going reset to interval
    {
        // THIS IS WHERE I ADDED MY SKIP VALUES TOGETHER
        // So value from last click + value from this click

        _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        _time = Interval;
        _dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
}

// Method to run when timer ticks over
private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // if the timer has reached below zero
    if (_time <= TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        _dispatcherTimer = null;
        _time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);

        // HERE IS WHERE WE CAN NOW SKIP VIDEO BY 
        // THE SKIP SPEED WE HAVE ACCUMULATED   
    }
    else
    {
        _time = _time.Add(-Interval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess i'm the laziest person here...

```
public class PostponeCommand : ICommand
    {
        private TimeSpan _delay;
        private Action<object> _command;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancellation;

        public PostponeCommand(Action<object> command, int delayMs)
        {
            this._command = command;
            this._delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delayMs);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public async void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _cancellation?.Cancel();
            _cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(_delay, _cancellation.Token);
                _command?.Invoke(parameter);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                // canceled
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

Comment: This just basically delays the execute of the command. Im looking for a way to track the number of clicks during that delay

Comment: @Sam neither your question nor comments indicate that... you should edit your question then